# Why can't typescript infer an argument's type if it is a generic function using `keyof`?

Tags: typescript

Why does this yeild an error?

```
type MyType = {
    a: string, b: string
}


function cantInfer<In, Out>(fn: (i: In) => Out, i: In) {

}

function myFunction<K extends keyof MyType>(key: K): string {
    return '';
}

cantInfer(myFunction, 'a');
```

But this doesn't:

```
type MyType = {
    a: string, b: string
}


function cantInfer<In, Out>(fn: (i: In) => Out, i: In) {

}

function myFunction(key: keyof MyType): string {
    return '';
}

cantInfer(myFunction, 'a');
```

Note, the missing `<K extends keyof MyType>` in `myFunction`

Comment: Problem is that it cannot infer K because it is not used at all in myFunction's arguments and return value. Have you tried `function myFunction<K>(key: K): string`

Comment: Just updated to a better example. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be noted that your first example does type-check when `strictFunctionTypes` is disabled. This disables bivariant parameter checking for function types. Without this check, the compiler allows code that may be unsound at runtime.

A good explanation can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant):

> ... the question of whether a more-specific-type-accepting function should be assignable to a function accepting a less-specific type provides a prerequisite answer to whether an array of that more specific type should be assignable to an array of a less specific type. Having the latter not be the case would not be an acceptable type system in the vast majority of cases, so we have to take a correctness trade-off for the specific case of function argument types.

You fix the issue in your second example by making the type parameters for `myFunction` concrete: `keyof MyType` resolves to `string` at compile time, meaning the type signature for `myFunction` is effectively `myFunction(key: string): string`

The following example type-checks by doing the opposite—It makes the type constraints on `canInfer` less permissive ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20MyType%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20canInfer%3CIn%20extends%20keyof%20MyType%2C%20Out%3E(fn%3A%20(i%3A%20In)%20%3D%3E%20Out%2C%20i%3A%20In)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20fn(i)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20myFunction%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20MyType%3E(key%3A%20K)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20myType%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b%3A%20%22bar%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20myType%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(canInfer(myFunction%2C%20'a'))%3B)):

```
type MyType = {
    a: string, b: string
}

function canInfer<In extends keyof MyType, Out>(fn: (i: In) => Out, i: In) {
    return fn(i);
}

function myFunction<K extends keyof MyType>(key: K): string {
    let myType = {
        a: "foo",
        b: "bar"
    }
    return myType[key];
}

alert(canInfer(myFunction, 'a'));
```